# biztalk envelope

Tags: xsd, biztalk, envelope

Suppose I would like to debatch a rootnode/child/child/repeatingnode node from my source message.  I would set the Body Xpath to rootnode/child/child/...

But now, whenever there's a source message wherein the rootnode/child/child/ node does not exist, the receive port fails.  (Body Xpath could not be executed, off course).

Any idea how to solve that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't conditionally process an envelope - the pipeline will now expect the envelope to be present.

Can you separate your non-enveloped messages into a separate pipeline? This would be the most logical approach.